# Notice: Undefined index: # in /var/www/...../magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Reorder/Renderer/Action.php on line 110

Tags: magento2

in my case I want to just add options in my grid like 'renew' and 'delete' inside select 'view' inside the file 'Action.php' ,but i face some error tells me what i mention in the question above , can anyone tells how were is the problem in the foreach inside the function '_actionsToHtml'

here is the function _actionsToHtml():

```
protected function _actionsToHtml(array $actions = [])
    {
        $html = [];
        $attributesObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        $attributesObject1 = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        $attributesObject2 = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();

        if (empty($actions)) {
            $actions = $this->_actions;
        }

        foreach ($actions as $action) {
            $attributesObject->setData($action['view']);
            $attributesObject1->setData($action['renew']);
            $attributesObject2->setData($action['delete']);
            $html[] = '<a ' . $attributesObject->serialize() . '>' . $action['#'] . '</a>';
            $html[] = '<a ' . $attributesObject1->serialize() . '>' . $action['#'] . '</a>';
            $html[] = '<a ' . $attributesObject2->serialize() . '>' . $action['#'] . '</a>';
            var_dump($html);
        }
        return implode('', $html);
    }
```

> and here is the function render also :

```
public function render(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)
    {
        $this->_actions = [];
        if ($this->_salesReorder->canReorder($row->getId())) {
            $reorderAction = [
                'view' => [
                    'href' => $this->getUrl('sales/order_create/reorder', ['order_id' => $row->getId()]),
                    'label' => __('View'),
                ],
                'renew' => [
                    'href' => $this->getUrl('sales/order_create/reorder', ['order_id' => $row->getId()]),
                    'label' => __('Renew'),
                ],
                'delete' => [
                    'href' => $this->getUrl('sales/order_create/reorder', ['order_id' => $row->getId()]),
                    'label' => __('Delete'),
                    'confirm' => [
                        'title' => __('Delete'),
                        'message' => __('Are you sure you want to delete this row ?'),
                    ],
                ],
            ];
            $this->addToActions($reorderAction);
        }
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'adminhtml_customer_orders_add_action_renderer',
            ['renderer' => $this, 'row' => $row]
        );
        return $this->_actionsToHtml();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **your $action variable is array please print and check which index are present.**

```
foreach ($actions as $action) {
            $attributesObject->setData($action['view']);
            $attributesObject1->setData($action['renew']);
            $attributesObject2->setData($action['delete']);
            $html[] = '<a ' . $attributesObject->serialize() . '>' . $action['view']['label']. '</a>';
            $html[] = '<a ' . $attributesObject1->serialize() . '>' . $action['renew']['label']. '</a>';
            $html[] = '<a ' . $attributesObject2->serialize() . '>' . $action['delete']['label'] . '</a>';
            //var_dump($html);
        }
```

> **you define invalid key to array variable.**

Comment: it tells me that ==> Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/ecommerce-web/web/vendor/magento/framework/DataObject.php on line 454 [] []

Comment: This error comes from this code return implode('', $html);

Comment: Please learn about this function https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-imploding-exploding/amp/